# what is Quaternion , and how to use a Quaternion lerp in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I want to make an object rotate on a particular axis at I tried using

```
void Rotate () {
        transform.Rotate(0,0,0);
   }
```

but it just rotate instantly , than i learned about *Quaternion* and everything went above my head , i didn't understand anything.
I just know that i know that there is a *Lerp* and *Slerp*.
But i don't know how to use them, I want to make the object rotate from its current rotation to a specific axis
with a *Lerp*.
Please Help Me!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to research before asking here. Googling same question will get you to the official docs of Unity about Quaternion [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html).

Following is the simple example to show how to rotate with transform locally and with world space.

```
void Update()
        {
            // Rotate the object around its local X axis at 1 degree per second
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
    
            // ...also rotate around the World's Y axis
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
```

Following shows how to use Quaternion

```
 // Interpolates rotation between the rotations
    // of from and to.
    // (Choose from and to not to be the same as
    // the object you attach this script to)

    Transform from;
    Transform to;
    float speed = 0.1f;
    void Update()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, Time.time * speed);
    }
```

Also you need to use Time.deltaTime to rotate it smoothly. In your question you are just assigning the values and that's why you don't see it rotating.

Comment: i already search but i couldn't understand anything and always go to unity docs in search for but i couldn't understand anything

Comment: try youtube also. sometime it helps with visual understanding.